# resources :users, :as => 'members' equvalent in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

So in Rails2 you could setup a route like this:

```
resources :users, :as => 'members'
```

This way you still have your `users_path` but it matches `/members`

Now, how do you go about doing this in Rails3? `:as` parameter here means totally different thing and I can't find what makes it work as before.

Comment: What I was looking for was `:path`. Works the same way as old `:as`

Comment: You should mark Matt's answer as the solution for future visitors to this question as he has given the same solution that you have. In the future if you find the solution yourself, you can add the answer and mark it as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `:path` option:

```
resources :users, :path => 'members'
```

Tested it on my app and the `users_path` still works, but matches `/members` as required. It doesn't match `/users`.